# Game view is slower than build - unity 2017.2.0f3

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am creating a sample 2D Unity tutorial.
If I run the game using play mode in the UnityEditor, the game seems **very slow**, and skips some frames. The standalone version runs smooth.

Did I configure something wrong?

[image: Lighting Settings]
[image: Lighting Settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is my display driver. The driver installed in my system is Microsoft display adapter, the one which is installed during the WINDOWS 10 OS installation. I just updated the driver to intel HD graphics which is opt for my graphics hardware, now unity works fine.

Answer (score 3):

**Thats normal.**

When you compare the FPS from UnityPlayer to Standalone, you will see that the Standalone application will perform alot better.

[Here is a article, which describes the speed differences](https://jacksondunstan.com/articles/2955)

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: But its difficult to test the game in unity3d editor. due to this problem i test the game by build it every time i want to test.

Comment: Define your scripts to Manager assemblies. That way Unity does'nt need to compile all scripts all over again in build.